Help. It's not compiling!
This is part 4, see for part 3: The answer is not single

Oh no, it's not compiling!
Can you please find the bugs and help solving it?



2nd
3rd
7th
5th
3rd
5th
4th

















6th
6th
5th
3rd
2nd
2nd
1st















I don’t think there should be a rhino inside your program…

First we identify the objects

 COW, COFFEE, CIRCUMFERENCE, DROPBOX, RIYADH, YELLOW, RHINO, IPHONE, BRIDGE, CAMERA, TARGET, TOAST, FRIDGE, SNAKE

Then we

 index into them using the ordinal numbers: C[O]W, CO[F]FEE, CIRCUM[F]ERENCE, DROP[B]OX, RI[Y]ADH, YELL[O]W, RHI[N]O, IPHON[E], BRIDG[E], CAME[R]A, TA[R]GET, T[O]AST, F[R]IDGE, [S]NAKE, which spells OFF BY ONE ERRORS, a common way to mistakenly index.

So we

 instead index one letter less or more than instructed and get [C]OW, C[O]FFEE, CIRCU[M]FERENCE, DRO[P]BOX, R[I]YADH, YEL[L]OW, RH[I]NO, IPHO[N]E, BRID[G]E, CAMER[A], TAR[G]ET, TO[A]ST, FR[I]DGE, S[N]AKE, which spells COMPILING AGAIN, which is necessary after correcting off-by-one errors.


Interesting to note that the changes are grouped by the resulting answer.

@BenjaminWang, that's not a coincidence ;) Also: "which is necessary after correcting" => I had in mind: "which is the result after correcting" :)

@caPNCApn, maybe you could update your answer to include the comments?

@Lezzup Oh I think I get it now. I was confused by your comment because, AFAIK, the things in question don't prevent compilation (wish they did) but just cause run-time errors.

@Lezzup Feel free to edit as you see fit :)
